# Ubuntu 16.04: cannot turn audio back on

Tags: sound, 16.04, pulseaudio, alsa

I recently changed the settings of my audio driver to play 24 bit / 96 Hz tracks. After a reboot, when I tried to play sound again, I noticed that the audio is muted and cannot be turned on again. I tried undoing all changes for the 24 bit settings and rebooting but it did not help. As I rarely turn the computer off I am not sure if this might have been caused by the things I changed or a result of the installation of some updates, as I update regularly.

```
teddy@Yoga-2:~$ amixer -D pulse sset Master 5%+
E: [pulseaudio] conf-parser.c: [/etc/pulse/daemon.conf:74] Missing '='.

ALSA lib pulse.c:243:(pulse_connect) PulseAudio: Unable to connect: Connection refused

amixer: Mixer attach pulse error: Connection refused
teddy@Yoga-2:~$ dpkg -l | grep pulse
ii  gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio:amd64               1.8.1-1ubuntu0.1                                    amd64        GStreamer plugin for PulseAudio
ii  libcanberra-pulse:amd64                     0.30-2.1ubuntu1                                     amd64        PulseAudio backend for libcanberra
ii  libpulse-mainloop-glib0:amd64               1:8.0-0ubuntu3                                      amd64        PulseAudio client libraries (glib support)
ii  libpulse0:amd64                             1:8.0-0ubuntu3                                      amd64        PulseAudio client libraries
ii  libpulsedsp:amd64                           1:8.0-0ubuntu3                                      amd64        PulseAudio OSS pre-load library
ii  pulseaudio                                  1:8.0-0ubuntu3                                      amd64        PulseAudio sound server
ii  pulseaudio-module-bluetooth                 1:8.0-0ubuntu3                                      amd64        Bluetooth module for PulseAudio sound server
ii  pulseaudio-module-x11                       1:8.0-0ubuntu3                                      amd64        X11 module for PulseAudio sound server
ii  pulseaudio-utils                            1:8.0-0ubuntu3                                      amd64        Command line tools for the PulseAudio sound server
```

Above is an output with the error I am receiving. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems while I was changing the settings of the audio, I have misspelled something on the configuration file and it is actually suggested by the error:

```
 E: [pulseaudio] conf-parser.c: [/etc/pulse/daemon.conf:74] Missing '='.
```

So I checked what was the original one and fixed it and it also fixed the issue.
So thanks to all who tried to help and sorry I might have wasted your time.

Answer (score 0):

Start "alsamixer" in a xterm instance, then "f4" to change to "capture" view, and here you can change the recording volume.

Source: https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/pulseaudio-unable-to-connect-935282/

(Since I can't comment directly, I'll respond to the original user's newly added answer here, to say that there are multiple ways a config file can change, not all of which would have involved user error. This speaking as someone who has been sitting, coding in Vim while SSHed onto a server, and saw the file I was editing change in front of my eyes. I'm assuming this was some sort of file corruption... ;) Of course, if you had been editing it before, it's possible you did it yourself too :P. I just don't assume with these things anymore...)

Comment: It says "The sound device does not have any capture controls." But I am not sure if input ever worked. And for audio output I am sure it worked.

Comment: @TeddyMarkov Have you tried `sudo apt update` and/or `sudo apt remove alsa-utils` followed by `sudo apt install alsa-utils`? Not sure if that'll help, but it's probably worth a try.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it did not help either. Really strange :/